# How to create a Elastic Search query for or condition

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to create a elastic query in java.

The query is

Select * from table name(col1==1 && col2==2) || (col3==3 && col4==4);

Answer (score 0):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

A combination of "Should" and "must" in elastic search query will get you to what you are looking for.

**must**

The clause (query) must appear in matching documents and will contribute to the score.

**filter**

The clause (query) must appear in matching documents. However unlike must the score of the query will be ignored. Filter clauses are executed in filter context, meaning that scoring is ignored and clauses are considered for caching.

**should**

The clause (query) should appear in the matching document.

**must_not**

The clause (query) must not appear in the matching documents. Clauses are executed in filter context meaning that scoring is ignored and clauses are considered for caching. Because scoring is ignored, a score of 0 for all documents is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use elastic search query if you want to query in sql style and return the results as JSON objects.
Example of the request:

```
POST _sql?format=json
{
  "query": """select "host.name", avg("system.fsstat.total_size.used")/avg(system.fsstat.total_size.total) * 100 as used_percent from "metricbeat*" where "@timestamp" >= NOW() - INTERVAL 60 MINUTE group by host.name"""
}
```

Link: https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elasticsearch-sql